# Boostrap Carousel caption link not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, carousel

I've found a similar question that was answered (by the OP), but the answer doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm trying to apply an  link to an image in Bootstrap carousel. That doesn't seem possible, so my next best option is to add a caption, and put a link in there. This is my code:

```
           <div class="item" >
                <img src="images/carousel-main-vets.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                 <span class="carousel-caption row-fluid">
                <p>click  <a href="https://youtu.be/eXpmMRl-6Ks" target="_blank">here</a> to watch video</p> 
               </span>
              </div>
```

The  style for the link actually shows up correctly on the page, but the link is not clickable. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hers a basic example of how to overlay text/link in a Bootstrap carousel.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x500/3498db/2980b9" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">Click <a href="https://youtu.be/eXpmMRl-6Ks" target="_blank"> here</a> to watch</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x500/9b59b6/8e44ad" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">Click <a href="https://youtu.be/eXpmMRl-6Ks" target="_blank"> here</a> to watch</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1500x500/34495e/2c3e50" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">Click <a href="https://youtu.be/eXpmMRl-6Ks" target="_blank"> here</a> to watch</div>
            </div>
        </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
                    </span></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-caption {
padding-bottom: 30px;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Seems lik that's exactly what I have, except where I have <span>, you have <div>... which I also tried, and got the same results.

Comment: Did you actually try the code i provided or just look at it?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, "which I also tried". ;) 

I had tried the div tags originally, thinking that it was in fact correct syntax. That didn't work (for me), so I looked around and found someone (on SO, I believe), who suggested using the <span> tags instead, saying that Boostrap's carousel doesn't read links if they're inside <div> tags. Not sure if that's fact or not, but it does seem to be true in my experience so far.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your efforts and posting the jsfiddle. I figured out the problem. Your code works perfectly, the issue was with this:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="position:relative;top:0px;z-index:-2">
```

Having the z-index value at -2 was causing the image/caption to be "back" farther, so the link wasn't working. Theoretically there was nothing in front of it "blocking" the link, but it was acting as if there were. Changing the z-index to "1" fixed the problem, then I just ended up removing that styling altogether.

Thanks very much for your help!